# Perl. how to open csv file, count how many rows and columns it has

Tags: perl, file, parsing, csv, count

I have a msft.csv file. Columns are separated by ",". which is actually a table. Can't post a picture, don't understand how to attach the file.

My task is:

1. Open the file and count and print how many rows and columns it has. Columns are separated by ",".
2. Open the file and print maximum, minimum for these columns: 
   Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close with the corresponding date
3. Open the file and calculate and print average  for these columns: 
   Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close

I have read some literature but I can't do anything useful. Actually all I was able to do is open the file and print it out.

I figured I should use Text::CSV  module, but I can't figure the right syntax.

I worked through first 6 chapters here http://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/
I've also read some info on http://perldoc.perl.org/index.html
but so far I'm a zero.

If it's possible - it would be great to see the solution with/without using module. 
I'll try to figure what you've done there, but if it's not too much trouble, I'll appreciate if you can explain at least something.

Any advice on what literature I should read? Any useful links?

p.s English is my second language, so please forgive me my grammar.

p.p.s I can do smtg with text files, but I haven't seen a single table example.

Comment: i tried using module. i tried using split.  its just i cant find proper example, and cant get the syntax right.  im stuck on the first tast- counting rows and columns. 
 #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;

 open FH, "msft.csv" or die $!;
 my @array = <FH>;
 my $scalar = @array;
 print "file has $scalar rows\n";


exit;  
the only way im able to get rows. how to split it into columns and count it?

the file 
Date Open High Low Close Volume Adj Close
8/6/2013 31.55 31.67 31.38 31.58 36331500 31.58

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'test.txt';
my $line;
my $lines = 0;
my @columns;

open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

$line = <$fh>;
@columns = split(',', $line);
$lines++ while <$fh>;
close $fh;

print "$lines lines\n";
print scalar @columns . " columns\n";
```

Comment: awesome - it worked. it produces the right output. 150 lines. 7 columns. now ill try to figure the process.  Thank you.

Comment: This works for the simple cases where there are no embedded commas inside the field values.  If you have to deal with that, the field will be enclosed in double quotes.  At that point, you need [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) or a similar module to handle the quoting correctly.

Comment: can you explain to me why do we use $line?  why $line = <$fh>; produces  the top line, but not the whole file.    and is there a difference between $fh and FH

Comment: $fh is just what i named the file handle. you can use what you want. FILE, FH. Both will work. As for why <$fh> only produces one line is because perl's builtin input record seperator defaults to one new line. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=287647

Comment: why do we use $line         $line = $fh  and than  
columns= split (',', $line) 

columns = split(',', <FH>)
columns = split(',', <$fh>)  
columns = split(',', $fh)   dont work.

Comment: can u please do the same using Text::CSV?

Comment: <> is called the diamond operator. It is used to read input. http://www.linuxtopia.org/Perl_Programming/pickingUpPerl_Input4.html

Comment: You could have also done `1 while <$fh>; $lines = $. - 1;` [`perldoc -v '$.'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.). It doesn't really matter in this example, but for more complex cases it could be useful to know.